# Smoke test for NFS?

Tags: nfs

Is there a simple test (like ping for determining if a network device is online) to determine if a NFS is enabled on a NAS?  Assume root-access to the NAS via terminal command-line is available.

On the NAS command line, I have tried:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep -i nfs
```

which did not return anything.   It may be that nfs is not running OR this is not the right command.

NAS Info:

```
uname -a
Linux WDMyCloud 3.10.39 #1 SMP Fri Aug  5 11:16:40 CST 2016 2014 T20p4 Build-git3f 24b4d armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `rpcinfo` and `showmount` programs *on the client* to check whether or not NFS is available as a remote service. Assuming you have `$remote` pointing to the name or IP address of the remote server (for example, `remote=192.168.1.1`) you can use commands such as these to interrogate the remote system:

```
# See what is out there
rpcinfo -p $remote

# Do we have NFS service
rpcinfo -T udp $remote 100003
rpcinfo -T tcp $remote 100003

# What shares are exported for us to use
showmount -e $remote
```